# Newbie: Name error on Sublime 3

Tags: python, nameerror

I'm using SublimeText 3. I installed SublimeREPL to run my current Python file so I could see returns on inputs on simple practice exercises. Here's my ridiculously simple code:

```
name = input("What is your name: ")
print name
```

I went to test it out and I am getting the following error:

```
    What is your name: Justin
    Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "Practice Exercise 1.py", line 2, in <module>
        name = input("What is your name: ")
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    NameError: name 'Justin' is not defined

***Repl Closed***
```

Seems like it wants to think of "Justin" as a function or something. If you guys could help me out, that'd be great.

Comment: maybe you are running python 2? try changing `input` to `raw_input`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need your input to be in quotes... i.e. What is your name: "Justin"

See here as an example https://www.python-course.eu/input.php

Comment: This solved it for me. I appreciate it a lot. I thought (after posting) that I could write for the input to be a string and that would return it as a string; but, quotes. Do the quotes only return the input as a string instead of wanting to read Justin as a function?

Comment: Yes I mean when putting it in from the console to type "Justin" in quotes.  The link I posted shows the exact error he has above "If you don't wrap your name into quotes, Python takes your name as a variable"...

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are running `Python2`. In which case, change [`input()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) to [`raw_input()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using python 3, `print` is a function and must be called using parenthesis.

```
print(name)
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I made that change. Didn't solve my issue, but I definitely appreciate the help to the right step.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you’re using python 2. You should probably be using python 3 unless you have a reason (eg: backwards compatibility). In python 2, `input()` interprets the input so you probably want to use `raw_input()` like this:

```
name = raw_input("What is your name: ")
print name
```